# Rails can't find my partial. Missing partial error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, partial

I generated a new model called Comment.

```
rails g model Comment user_id:integer content:text
rake db:migrate
```

Then I create a simple partial view, that I intend to call from another controller/view.

[image]

Inside of a Product show view:

```
.comments
  h3
    | Questions and Answers:
    small for #{@product.name}

    = render 'comments/new'
```

> Missing partial comments/new with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html],
>   :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :slim, :coffee]}.
>   Searched in:   *
>   "/Users/sergiotapia/Documents/Work/foobar/app/views"

I stopped and started the Rails application and it's still refusing to detect the partial. Am I overlooking something?

**I would prefer not to move the comment form to the Products folder.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Incorrect File Extension

Rename partial file to `_new.html.slim`. Currently `html` is **misspelt** as `hmtl`.

Comment: *sigh* - Time for some coffee.

Comment: Definitely need a coffee. Enjoy!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

> **2.2.4 Rendering an Arbitrary File**
>
> The render method can also use a view that's entirely outside of your
>   application (perhaps you're sharing views between two Rails
>   applications):
>
> ```
> render "/u/apps/warehouse_app/current/app/views/products/show"
> ```
>
> Rails determines that this is a file render because of the leading
>   slash character. To be explicit, you can use the :file option (which
>   was required on Rails 2.2 and earlier):
>
> ```
> render file:"/u/apps/warehouse_app/current/app/views/products/show"
> ```
>
> The :file option takes an absolute file-system path. Of course, you
>   need to have rights to the view that you're using to render the
>   content.

Taken from here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

**EDIT:**
Oh sure, the file name is not correct, didn't see that. ;) See Kirti Thorat's answer.

Comment: clearly problem is in naming partial file. See kirti Thorat's answer.